# Есть ли возможность создать круговой слайдер на С++ средствами wxWidgets?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Работаю в данный момент над интерфейсом для приложения, есть необходимость создать круговой слайдер. В официальных примерах ни слова, на форумах тоже не нашел, не мог бы кто-то ткнуть меня, что я упустил. Или же это вообще невозможно? Но я сомневаюсь в том что это невозможно - всё таки это С++. Что бы было более понятно прикрепляю картинку, чего-то похожего на то, что я хочу получить.

[image: Круговой слайдер]

Comment: Пример: https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Painting_your_custom_control